# Filtering popup menu

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

In general, I need to make a pop-up menu with a choice of a category, everything works for me, but there is one point that needs to be improved.

When the category has already been selected, it is necessary that in the `blog-filter` class, **All** should be changed to the **selected category**, I tried many options, but all the non-working ones turned out to be.

**html**

```
<div class="blog-filter">
    <div class="blog-filter_item active js-filter-blog-list" data-filter="all">All</div>
</div>
<div class="blog-filter-container">
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="blog-filter-title">Choose Category</h1>
    <div class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="blog-filter_item active" data-filter="all">All</div>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
        <div class="blog-filter_item" data-filter=".category_{{$category->id}}">{{ $category->title }} ({{ $category->articles_count }})</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
</div>

@foreach ($articles as $article)
    <div class="blog-list category_{{ $article->blog_category_id }}">
            <div class="article article--left" >
                <h2 class="article_title">{{ $article->title }}</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="article article--right">
                <h2 class="article_title">{{ $article->title }}</h2>
            </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**js**

```
$('.js-filter-blog-list').on('click', event => {
  const modalFilter = document.querySelector('.blog-filter-container');
  $(modalFilter).toggleClass('open');
});

document.querySelectorAll('.blog-filter_item').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document
      .querySelector('.blog-filter_item.active')
      .classList.remove('active');
    el.classList.add('active');

      var dataFilter = $(el).attr('data-filter');

      if (dataFilter == 'all') {
        $('.blog-list').show();
      }
      else {
        $('.blog-list').hide();
        $(dataFilter).show();
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: I find it a bit confusing, how useful is the presence of modal dialogue? you should synthesize your code in a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ...

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
        <div class="blog-filter_item" data-filter=".category_{{$category->id}}" value="{{ $category->title }} ({{ $category->articles_count }})>{{ $category->title }} ({{ $category->articles_count }})</div>
@endforeach
```

```
var dataFilter = $(el).attr('data-filter');
var value = $(el).attr('value');

      if (dataFilter == 'all') {
        $('.blog-list').show();
        $('.js-filter-blog-list').text('All');
      }
      else {
        $('.blog-list').hide();
        $(dataFilter).show();
        $('.js-filter-blog-list').text(value);
      }
```